# Cancel request to PHP page results in another PHP page delayed responding

Tags: php, ldap

I am developing a login page which look into LDAP and MySQL database for user authentication. The idea is to request two PHP page simultaneously, any one complete request will cancel the other one request.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(username, password) {
    var ldap = $q.defer();
    var userTable = $q.defer();

    $http({
            timeout: userTable.promise,
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'crud/00loginUserTable.php',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.message != "ok")
                alert("Tak OK");
            else {
                sessionStorage.jwt = response.data.jwt;
                ldap.resolve();
                window.location.href = "index.php";
            }
        });

    $http({
            timeout: ldap.promise,
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'crud/00loginLDAP.php',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.message != "ok")
                alert("Tak OK");
            else {
                sessionStorage.jwt = response.data.jwt;
                userTable.resolve();
                window.location.href = "index.php";
            }
        });
};
```

This code actually works. BUT...

There is 1.3 minute delay before `window.location.href = "index.php";` could be execute. As I found out, it is something to do with PHP. I tried changing `window.location.href = "index.php";` to `window.location.href = "index.html";`. Viola! No delay. So it seems the `index.php` is waiting for `00loginLDAP.php` to timeout before responding.

I know the problem, but I don't know the solution.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the first request is cancelling the second request. I don't think that it would do so. Both requests will get completed.

Comment: Both requests did get completed if both were success/failed. But this one, the LDAP is purposely failed (no connection to the LDAP server here at my place). The MySQL connection is successful, cancel the other request almost instantly, but my problem is the delay..

Comment: i think ` ldap.resolve();` before `window.href` is creating problem. Cross confirm this by trying a `console.log()` after ` ldap.resolve();` to check if flow is continued or returned.

Comment: The log appear instantly..

Comment: try returning the promise `return ldap.promise;`

Comment: where should i put the code?

Comment: check answer. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learnt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997102/will-a-script-continue-to-run-even-after-closing-a-page/5997852#5997852),  merely canceling the $http request won't stop the PHP execution. The reason the other PHP page wait until the first PHP page is finish, because both using `session_start();`.

I quote:

> Moreover if you are using PHP session, they are another tricky
>   situation. For example, if you are doing AJAX, and you actually send
>   two AJAX request to a PHP script and that PHP script has need of
>   session with session_start(). The first AJAX query will work normally,
>   however the second one will have to wait until the first call is
>   finish, because the first script has a locked on the session. The
>   first script could eventually prematurely release the session with
>   session_write_close();

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.submitForm().then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
   window.location.href = "index.php";
});

$scope.submitForm = function(username, password) {
    var ldap = $q.defer();
    var userTable = $q.defer();

    $http({
            timeout: userTable.promise,
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'crud/00loginUserTable.php',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.message != "ok")
                alert("Tak OK");
            else {
                sessionStorage.jwt = response.data.jwt;
                ldap.resolve('DataTable Response');
                return ldap.promise;
            }
        });

    $http({
            timeout: ldap.promise,
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'crud/00loginLDAP.php',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.message != "ok")
                alert("Tak OK");
            else {
                sessionStorage.jwt = response.data.jwt;
                userTable.resolve('LDAP response');
                return userTable.promise;
            }
        });
};
```

Use this .. passing  `ldap.resolve('DataTable Response');` data inside `resolve()` is optional. if you want to pass some message then use.

Comment: Error: $scope.submitForm is not a function

Comment: pass `username` and `password` i missed them... `$scope.submitForm(username,password).then(function(data)`

Comment: still not working, i even wrap the $scope.submitForm in another function, also not working.. same error message..

Comment: Error: $scope.submitForm is not a function

Comment: OK. Found the problem. Nothing to do with even the JS! It's PHP. Rewording my question.